# Not able to save parent id when handling OneToMany relationship

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am facing some difficulty while maintaning one-to-many relationship through Spring JPA. We have two entities parent and child. I have defined many to one relationship like this

parent entity

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = parent)
Set<Child> childs;
```

child entity

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name=""parent_id)
private Parent parent;
```

Below is the code in my service to save the parent.

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.setName("name");
List<Child> children= new ArrayList<>();
Child child1 = new Child();
child1.setAge(10);
children.add(child1);
Child child2 = new Child();
child2.setAge(11);
children.add(child1);
parent.setChilds(children)
parentReposiroty.save(parent);
```

It saving data in both table but in child table parent_id is null. Kindly suggest what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When managing bidirectional relationship you should also set parent for each child when saving from parent side. so see below to update your code to set parent for child by adding `child1.setParent(parent);` and  `child2.setParent(parent);`

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.setName("name");
List<Child> children= new ArrayList<>();
Child child1 = new Child();
child1.setAge(10);

child1.setParent(parent);

children.add(child1);
Child child2 = new Child();
child2.setAge(11);

child2.setParent(parent);

children.add(child1);
parent.setChilds(children)
parentReposiroty.save(parent);
```